# IRQ and interrupt vector

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, intel

In this document,http://retired.beyondlogic.org/serial/serial1.htm#30,

the IRQ of COM3 is 4 and its interrrupt vector is 0C.

But the int 0C interrupt vector is reserved for  **Stack Fault** ....

This is quite confusing.When COM3 interrupts ,the **Stack Fault** happens at the same time?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [beyondlogic.com](http://retired.beyondlogic.org/serial/serial1.htm#30) table shows the *default* mapping, as set up by the BIOS, from an IRQ (the external interrupt signal going into the Programmable Interrupt Controller (PIC)) to the interrupt or exception number as seen by the CPU. So in this case the interrupt line from the serial port is connected to PIC input 3, which when asserted will cause the CPU to run the interrupt/exception handler pointed to by entry 0xC in the interrupt vector table.

The same thing happens with exceptions generated internally by the CPU. To continue with your example, a stack fault causes the exception hander pointed to by entry 0xC in the in interrupt vector table to be run.

So in this case its not that the serial port interrupt causes a stack fault, but that two different events can cause the same interrupt/exception handler to run.

This clash is not desirable. In theory the interrupt/exception handler code could check to see what actually caused the handler to run, but this would take time, so we need a better solution.

However first it is worth looking at what caused this clash in the first place. Intel always reserved entries less than 0x20 for internal exceptions, but on the 8086 only entries 0 to 4 were used, so when when the original IBM PC mapped interrupts to 8 and above this wasn't a problem.

With the introduction of the 80386 and protected mode the number of exceptions was increased, and entries 5 to 0x14 were now used, which meant that clashes could occur with interrupts when the default IRQ mapping was used.

So the solution used by most modern operating systems which run in protected mode is to reprogram the PIC to so that interrupts use interrupt vector numbers 0x20 or greater. See [OSDev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/PIC#Programming_with_the_8259_PIC) for more details or for a concrete example see how [Linux](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.8/source/arch/x86/kernel/i8259.c#L341) does this.

Comment: Thank you very much,quite helpful!